# browserHistory undefined with React Router 2.00 release candidates

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

With React Router 2.0.0rc1-5 I have been getting browserHistory as undefined after import:

`import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'`

The package seems to be installed correctly, but regardless of the version and whether on server or client, I have gotten the same result.

Maybe this a known bug?

Comment: With newer versions of `react-router`, you get the history creator from the `history` package. Take a look at [the docs](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/1.0.x/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md).

Comment: From the master branch, I believe they are actually packaging browserHistory into react-router now

Comment: WIth the 2.0 rcs, I get undefined on the server... and in the browser I get ```connect.js?243b:60 Uncaught TypeError: finalMapStateToProps is not a function``` (which seems like a Redux issue). I think it is related to the rendering of React Router though, as I receive the same error on the server unless I remove the router from my ```renderToString```

Comment: Gotcha. It actually *should* return `undefined` on the server, if I'm [reading the code correctly](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v2.0.0-rc5/modules/createRouterHistory.js#L7). You wouldn't use the history on the server, opting instead for [`match` and `RoutingContext`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/guides/advanced/ServerRendering.md). And the browser error sounds like a Redux configuration problem, perhaps in your code - feel free to add it above and we can take a look.

Comment: It seems as though it was in fact a Redux syntax issue. Once I wasn't using ```browserHistory``` on the server, as u said, I avoided the undefined issue. My redux error was related to my use of ```connect()``` in a container. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @hoodsy can you elaborate what the solution in your container was?

Answer (score 1):

See useRouterHistory:
https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#using-custom-histories

I'm using this in server-side:

```
import {Router, RouterContext, match, useRouterHistory} from 'react-router';
import {createMemoryHistory} from 'history';

// ...
const appHistory = useRouterHistory(createMemoryHistory)({});
const component = (
  <Provider store={store} key="provider">
    <Router routes={routes} history={appHistory} />
  </Provider>
);
```

Comment: you can install `react-router` version 3.0, like this : `npm install --save react-router@3.0` the should also update your webpack configuration file. And you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Install react-router version 3.0

`npm install --save react-router@3.0` or

`yarn add react-router@3.0`

Then, the both the methods work:

**Method 1**

```
import { Router, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router';
import {createMemoryHistory} from 'history';
import routes from './routes';

const appHistory = useRouterHistory(createMemoryHistory)({});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={appHistory} routes={routes}/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Method 2**

```
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';

ReactDOM.render(
    // or hashHistory
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes}/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```